# To what degree can Eyefi uploads be automated?

Tags: wireless, eye-fi

I want to help a friend who is not very computer / camera literate. I want to set it up, so as soon as she's back in the house, the photos are going to go from memory card automatically to a photo service, like flickr. I heard about Eye-Fi cards.

- Does Eyefi card autoamtically clean up / delete the photos once it's uploaded to a PC? so she does not have to do any manual clean up
- Is there a way to control when the syncing happens on Eye-fi card? So it does not automatically trigger, but start working when you want. How does Eye-fi card triggers synching?

Hardware: she has a normal point and shoot canon digital camera. A windows XP PC.

Thanks.

Comment: When you have a specific question, it's best to actually make that the question title. Otherwise, it's not likely to help anyone else with similar questions find help. And, since you have two questions, please ask them separately.

Comment: Teach a friend to fish and she'll be able to upload photos on her own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Eyefi card can be setup to automatically upload photos to a PC or Mac - **if your camera supports the Eyefi card**.  I use it for wireless tethered shooting with the images going directly into Lightroom.  Eyefi does not automatically clean up/delete photos - they will be both on the card and the PC until you delete them.  Transmission should happen automatically when the camera and PC connect with each other on the wifi network.  Sometimes my camera will get confused and stop sending, and I have to turn the camera off and back on to get things going again.